# How can a daterange field be created in GORM?

Tags: database, postgresql, go, orm, go-gorm

It's not common for all DBMS, but PostgreSQL has a *daterange* datatype. Is there a way to first of all, create and then populate a PostgreSQL daterange field in GORM, or is the only solution to just create a `start_datetime` and an `end_datetime` field and keep the implementation more generic?